# Inserting dynamic information into the database (dynamic drop-down menu)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code, that gets the categories from the database and displays them on a dropdown menu. Now, what I want to do, Is when something is selected and the button `isset`, get the ID of that category (table: `categories` ,row `category_id`) then submit it into (table: `posts` ,row `category_id`). I don't know how to get the ID of the category that was selected in the dropdown. Thanks.
`$db` variable is the database connection.

This is what I've got so far. This is the submission of the data to the database:

```
include('../includes/db_connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $newTitle = $_POST['newTitle'];
    $newPost = $_POST['newPost'];
    $newCategory = $_POST['newCategory'];
    $my_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    if(!empty($newPost))
        if(!empty($newTitle)){
    $sql="INSERT INTO posts  (title, body, category_id)
VALUES('$newTitle', '$newPost', '$newCategory')";
    $query = $db->query($sql);
    if($query){
            echo "Post entered to database";
        }else{
            echo "Error Submitting the data";
        }
    }
}
```

This is the select:

```
<textarea name="newPost" cols="176" rows="25"/></textarea><br>
<select name=""="newCategory" id="newCategory">
    <option value="0">Select category</option>
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM categories");
    if ( $result ) {
        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {

            echo '<option value="' . $row['category'] . '">' . $row['category'] . '</option>';

        }
    } else {
        echo 'Couldn\'t fetch Categories from MySQL.';
    }
?>
```

Ps - I know this is easily injectable, you don't need to tell me, Just answer the question please :)

Comment: Don't do `value="<name>"` in your selector, do `value="<id>"`.

Comment: you have a bug in your code snippet above... `name=""="newCategory"` should be `name="newCategory"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mostly likely just need to change this line, and have the `value` be the category primary key like `id` or whatever it is called.

```
echo "<option value='{$row['id']}'>{$row['category']}</option>";
```

Otherwise after submit you would have to run a mysql query to find the `id` by searching where `category='$newCategory'`

Comment: Look at the html source code generated. Are all the id's in the option values correctly?